# lstat() blocks for 15 minutes

Tags: linux, windows

My Linux (Fedora) machine becomes unresponsive for about 15 minutes when I open/save a file. I investigated and it's related to a Windows mounted directory in /mnt. I can reproduce with a simple 'ls -al /mnt'. All subsequent ls commands return quickly. After a period of time the same problem shows up and I'm forced to take another 15 minute break...

strace and ltrace both point to lstat():

```
# strace
13:37:22 lstat("/mnt/Todo-Dino", 0x211ce40) = -1 EHOSTDOWN (Host is down)
13:52:24 open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

# ltrace
13:37:22 __lxstat(1, "/mnt/Todo-Dino", 0x01e1ee40)                                             = -1
13:52:24 dcgettext(0, 0x4120ce, 5, 0, 0x1e24850)

mnt$ ls -al
ls: cannot access Todo-Dino: Host is down
total 40
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? Todo-Dino
```

The Windows machine with a mount in above /mnt/Todo-Dino is not really down as reported. Even in it would be down, 15 mins is quite a long wait...

After the 15 minute period the directory shows up as expected:

```
mnt$ ls -al
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root 12288 Feb  4 12:36 Todo-Dino
```

fstab has:

```
//192.168.1.1/Todo                      /mnt/Todo-Dino          cifs    username=XXX,password=XXX,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,auto,users 0 0
```

Any idea how to cure this issue? From where the magic 15 minute delay?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you verify that it's not a (temporary) network issue. i.e. while stat is hanging, can you ping or otherwise communicate over the network from the linux machine to the windows machine ?

Comment: @nos I've just tried it. Steps: 1) Woken up the Windows machine 2) Ping-ing it (192.168.1.1) from Linux works 3) 'ls' still hangs on Linux. In fact step 2 is redundant - I'm really connecting to the Linux machine from the Windows one via VNC... The Linux box only 'looses' that mounted dir and it takes it 15 mins to reacquire it. It's a 4-5 years old Fedora. There might be a Samba config that needs tweaking to at least  reduce that 15 mins to something acceptable.

Comment: Actually I've discovered there was the serverfault community where such problems are discussed. A similar one issue: http://serverfault.com/questions/622238/linux-cifs-samba-mount-hangs-for-several-minutes. As a workaround I could try a suggestion from there - cron job every minute that 'exercises' the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get to the bottom of this issue but at least there's a simple cure. Similar to what was suggested on a similar thread, cron-ed the listing of /mnt every 5 mins. May be too often but who cares? Now no forced 15 minutes breaks when using the machine!

```
    * * * * /bin/ls -al /mnt > /dev/null 2>&1
    5 * * * * /bin/ls -al /mnt > /dev/null 2>&1
    ...
```